# Jupyter programmatically execute an hotkey

Tags: python, jupyter, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I am trying to figure out if there is any code to execute a Jupyter hotkey.

I am specifically interested in "scroll up" hotkey: `Shift` + `Space`.
Is it possible to write code that, when executed, produce an effect equivalent to pressing `Shift` + `Space`, thus scrolling up the notebook?

I have not found anything relevant. I have tried to explore `IPython` module and its submodules, to no avail!

If what I am asking is impossible or "wrong", I would still appreciate an explanation. Why it is impossible to programmatically execute a Jupyter hotkey? What should I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit keyboard shortcuts from Help menu as suggested in the documentation:
https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebook.html?highlight=shift%20space#keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer my question. I do not need to set personalized keyboard shortcuts. I need to write some code in a notebook cell that, when executed, performs the same action that is performed when pressing the hotkeys.